# How many tags are needed for ArcPy questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At the moment we have two `arcpy*` tags:

- [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) - 4,262 questions including

  - 182 questions and answers tagged [arcpy mentioning arcpy.mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcpy%5D+arcpy.mapping); and
  - 203 questions and answers tagged [arcpy mentioning arcpy.sa](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcpy%5D+arcpy.sa)
  - 3 questions and answers tagged [arcpy mentioning arcpy.na](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcpy%5D+arcpy.na)
  - 6 questions and answers tagged [arcpy mentioning arcpy.mp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcpy%5D+arcpy.mp)
- [arcpy-mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy-mapping) - 174 questions

Do we have the right number of ArcPy tags?

Comment: Actually, there are 82 [questions tagged with arcpy containing arcpy.mapping](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcpy%5D+arcpy.mapping+is%3Aquestion), 100 of those were answers. I wouldn't re-tag a question based on the content of an answer in most situations... Similarly, there are 183 questions tagged [arcpy that mention arcpy.sa](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcpy%5D+arcpy.sa+is%3Aquestion) so perhaps arcpy.sa should be a tag as well.

Comment: @EvilGenius Thanks - I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Tags [tag:arcpy-mapping], [tag:arcpy.mapping], [tag:arcpy.mp], [tag:arcpy.sa], [tag:arcpy.na] and [tag:arcpy.da] are now all synonyms of [tag:arcpy].

Answer (score 5):

My preference would be to tag all ArcPy questions with [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) and to make [arcpy-mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy-mapping) a synonym of that.

When the question is about:

- arcpy.sa - add an additional tag for [spatial-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-analyst)
- arcpy.na - add an additional tag for [network-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-analyst)
- using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro - add an additional tag for [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro)

Comment: This has to be the way to go. It's easy enough and doesn't create confusion with multiple [tag:arcpy] tags.